# java stream joining for field which itself is a class

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

For a field of the same class, I can use

```java
stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

How to use the stream in one line to join id of Item from the given list of RejectItem?

```
class RejectItem {
    Item item;
    String reason;
}

class Item {
    Long id;
    Date createdOn;
}

// ..................

List<RejectItem> ri;
String commaSepIdString = ri.stream ??
```

Comment: No i want to know if it can be done in single stream as with field of one class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this. Don't directly use .toString() in case you have nulls as your using Long and not long.

```java
list.stream().map(item -> String.valueOf(item.item.id)).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

I would suggest add getters and setters for your classes. Use the lombok annotation which minimise the code.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a lambda expression like this:

```java
List<RejectItem> rejectedItems = ...

String result = rejectedItems.stream()
        .map(ri -> ri.item.id.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map function also to build a "path" trough function calls, like

```
String commaSepIdString = ri.stream().map(ri -> ri.item).map(i -> i.id).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Only one `map()` call is needed, not 3.

Comment: @Andreas some might prefer three `map`, with method references over lambda though, a matter of choice?

Comment: @Naman but this answer has even more lambda expressions than a single `map` step.